# QT Excel - Open to Read/Write

Tags: excel, qt

I'd like to know what's the best way to open excel file (.xlsx) (Need to write and read or eventually only read)
I've already tried this (it's only test):

```
void MainWindow::openExcel()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC", "xls_connection");
    db.setDatabaseName("DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls,*.xlsx,*.xlsm,*.xlsb)};DBQ=" + QString ("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\file.xlsx") );
    if(db.open())
    {
        QSqlQuery query("select * from [" + QString("Sheet1") + "$A1:B5]");

    while (query.next())
    {
        //reading columns
        QString column1= query.value(0).toString();
        qDebug()<<column1;
    }
        db.close();
        QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("xls_connection");
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"Failed";
    }
}
```

but it couldn't open such file ("Failed"). I would be glad if anyone could say where's a problem
//Maybe also recommend any good books or tutorials for QT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use ODBC for Excel on Windows, the **MS Access Database Engine** must be downloaded as mentioned in the [wiki Note](http://wiki.qt.io/Handling_Microsoft_Excel_file_format) from which this sample code was tested (Win7/ qt4.9 , Win10/ qt 5.7) , then the connection can work. alternatively in the same Qt wiki [Content](http://wiki.qt.io/Handling_Microsoft_Excel_file_format#Reading_.2F_Writing), you can find different ways of opening MS Excel with Qt.

Comment: My mistake , didn't read whole text before . Maybe it's stupid question but i need to ask : If I Use ODBC and would give ready program to someone , do they need to also install MS Engine or is it only required on coding stage?

Comment: No its a plugin or driver, it has to be part of your deployment unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

You can use ActivX object to work with excel file - 
[ActiveX Excel example](https://wiki.qt.io/Using_ActiveX_Object_in_Qt)

Other option to read-write into excel file format (.xlsx) - 
[QtXlsxWriter](https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtXlsxWriter)